# How to count [any name from a list of names] + [specific last name] in a block of text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-analysis

first time post here. I’m hoping I can find a little help on something I’m trying to accomplish in terms of text analysis.

First, I’m doing this in python and would like to remain in python as this function would be part of a larger, otherwise healthy tool I’m happy with. I have NLKT and Anaconda all set up as well, so drawing on those resources is also possible.

I’ve been working on a tool that tracks and adds up references to city names in large blocks of text. For instance, the tool can count how many times “Chicago,” “New York” or “Los Angeles,” “San Francisco” etc… are detected in a text chunk and can rank them.

The current problem I am having is figuring out how to remove false positives from city names that are also last names. So, for instance, I would want to count, say Jackson Mississippi, but not count “Frank Jackson” “Jane Jackson” etc…

What I would like to do however is figure out a way to account for any false positive that might be [any name from a long list of first names] + [Select last name].

I have assembled a list of ~5000 first names from the census data that I can also bring into python as a list. I can also check true/false to find if a name is on that list, so I know I’m getting closer.

However, what I can’t figure out is how to express what I want, which is something like (I’ll use Jackson as an example again):

```
totalfirstnamejacksoncount = count (“[any name from census list] + Jackson”)
```

More or less. Is there some way I can phrase it as a wildcard from census list so ? Set a variable that would read as “any item in this list” so I could go “anynamevariable + Jackson,”?  Or is there any other way to denote something like “any word in census list + Jackson”?

Ideally, my aim is to get a total count of “[Any first name] + [Specified last name]” so I can a) subtract them from the total of [Last name that is also a city name] count and maybe use that count for some other refinements.

In a worst case scenario I can see a way I could directly modify the census list and add  Jackson (or whatever last name I need) to each name and have the lines manually add, but I feel like that would make a complete mess of my code when you look at ~5000 names for each name I’d like to do.

Sorry for the long-winded post. I appreciate your help with all this. If you have other suggestions you think might be better ways to approach it I’m happy to hear those out as well.

Comment: First things first, NLTK features corpus `nltk.corpus.names` that has a list of ~8,000 English names, which probably more complete than the list that you collected.

Comment: Could you make a list of the word preceding every instance of "Jackson" and loop through it to check if it's in your nltk.corpus.names?

Comment: I thought about creating a concordance and then checking for any names from the list in the corpus, but then there is the matter of getting the concordance in NLTK to output to variable (which it doesn't want to do) as well as tuning the concordance length so that it would catch the names, but not over catch. I thought I would look into this first as it seemed like if I could just go ([any from this list] + "Jackson") might be the most straightforward way. Also, thank you for pointing out the NLTK names list. That might be a better way to go about assembling the first names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to use regular expressions in combination with the list of names from NLTK. Suppose your text is:

```
text = "I met Fred Jackson and Mary Jackson in Jackson Mississippi"
```

Take a list of all names and convert it in a (huge) regular expression:

```
jackson_names = re.compile("|".join(w + r"\s+" + "Jackson" \
                           for w in nltk.corpus.names.words()))
```

In case you are not familiar with regular expressions, `r'\s+'` means "separated by one or more white spaces" and `"|"` means "or". The regular expression can be expanded to handle other last names.

Now, extract all "Jackson" matches from your text:

```
jackson_catch = jackson_names.findall(text)
#['Fred Jackson', 'Mary Jackson']
len(jackson_catch)
#2
```

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thank you so much for your help on this. I just tested it and I've already got it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by assuming that you are able to work with your data by iterating through words, e.g.

```
s = 'Hello. I am a string.'
s.split()
Output: ['Hello.', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'string.']
```

and you have managed to normalize the words by eliminating punctuation, capitalization, etc.

So you have a list of words `words_list` (which is your text converted into a list) and an index `i` at which you think there might be a city name, OR it might be someone's last name falsely identified as a city name.  Let's call your list of first names `FIRST_NAMES`, which should be of type `set` (see comments).

```
if i >= 1:
  prev_word = words_list[i-1]
  if prev_word in FIRST_NAMES:
    # put false positive code here
  else:
    # put true positive code here
```

---

You may also prefer to use regular expressions, as they are more flexible and more powerful.  For example, you may notice that even after implementing this, you still have false positives or false negatives for some previously unforeseen reason.  RE's could allow you to quickly adapt to the new problem.

On the other hand, if performance is a primary concern, you may be better off not using something so powerful and flexible, so that you can hone your algorithm to fit your specific requirements and run as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Regardless of everything else, make sure that `FIRST_NAMES` is a set, not a list, because large lists have horrible lookup time.

Comment: I will add a note about that :)

Comment: Taking at look at this as well and will update when I get it working in the larger picture. Thank you very much for this as well!

Answer (score 0):

> The current problem I am having is figuring out how to remove false positives from city names that are also last names. So, for instance, I would want to count, say Jackson Mississippi, but not count “Frank Jackson” “Jane Jackson” etc…

The problem you have is called "named entity recognition", and is best solved with a classifier that takes multiple cues into account to find the named entities and classify them according to type (PERSON, ORGANIZATION, LOCATION, etc., or a similar list).

[Chapter 7](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) in the nltk book, and especially [section 3, Developing and evaluating chunkers](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#developing-and-evaluating-chunkers), walks you through the process of building and training a recognizer. Alternatively, you could install the Stanford named-entity recognizer and measure its performance on your data.

Comment: I'll take a look at this as well and see what I might be able to do with this. Thanks for the heads up on this!